# Can moderators migrate a question closed for another reason?

Tags: discussion, migration, vote-to-close

Saw a [question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1220220/when-do-i-know-that-im-addicted-to-stack-overflow-closed) that really belonged on meta.  It was already closed as not programming related.  I flagged it for a moderator as needing to be migrated not merely closed.  Now I'm wondering if that is even possible?

Answer (score 2):

Well, considering Bill explicitly mentioned that he didn't want to migrate it only to close it as a duplicate on the destination site... I'd guess "yes". If nothing else, a moderator could instantly re-open it and then close+migrate it.

Comment: Ah.  I didn't think about the ability for them to reopen instantly.

Comment: ...and I didn't see Bill's comment when I originally viewed the question.  I suppose it probably would be closed here too as an "exact duplicate."

Comment: You're both right.  We can (and I've done this) reopen questions just to migrate them immediately.  That question would be an exact duplicate of a question asked yesterday on here, so I just saved a step and closed it once on SO.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is entirely possible for a mod to reopen a question closed for any reason and then reclose it in the migration process to another site. I've actually done this a few times on SuperUser in the recent past.